# From a list of lists to a list of data records

Tags: haskell

I'm parsing a file that looks like this:

```
Good
id123
^
Bad
id456
^
Middle
id789
```

Records are separated by `^\n`, and fields within that record
are separated simply by `newlines`.

Reading this file and splitting, I end up with a list of lists that looks like this:

```
[["Good","id123",""],["Bad","id456",""],["Middle","id789",""]]
```

However, I fail to turn this into a list of Rec types.

Here's my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric,  OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Text as T
import Data.Text.IO as T

data Rec = Rec Text Text Text deriving Show  -- simple

main :: IO ()
main = do
    contents <- T.readFile "./dat.txf" 
    let seps = splitOn "^\n" contents
    let recs = fmap (splitOn "\n") seps
    print recs

main
```

Produces

```
[["Good","id123",""],["Bad","id456",""],["Middle","id789",""]]
```

As expected.  But trying to take this to the next step and turn these into Recs, with:

```
main_ :: IO ()
main_ = do
    contents <- T.readFile "./dat.txf" 
    let seps = splitOn "^\n" contents
    let recs = fmap (splitOn "\n") seps
    print recs
    print $ fmap (\(x, y, z) -> Rec x y z) recs
    -- print $ fmap (\r -> Rec r) recs
    -- let m = fmap (\x -> Rec [(x,x,x)]) recs 
    -- print m
    -- print $ fmap (\x -> Rec t3 x) recs
    -- where t3 [x,y,z] = (x,y,z)

main_
```

I get:

```
<interactive>:7:44: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Text]’ with ‘(Text, Text, Text)’
      Expected type: [(Text, Text, Text)]
        Actual type: [[Text]]
    • In the second argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘recs’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘fmap (\ (x, y, z) -> Rec x y z) recs’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ fmap (\ (x, y, z) -> Rec x y z) recs
```

or

```
main__ :: IO ()
main__ = do
    contents <- T.readFile "./dat.txf" 
    let seps = splitOn "^\n" contents
    let recs = fmap (splitOn "\n") seps
    print recs
    print $ fmap (\x -> Rec (f x)) recs
                            where f [a,b,c] = (a,b,c)    
main__

<interactive>:7:30: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’ with actual type ‘(Text, Text, Text)’
    • In the first argument of ‘Rec’, namely ‘(f x)’
      In the expression: Rec (f x)
      In the first argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘(\ x -> Rec (f x))’
```

What am I missing to turn the `[[Text]]` into `[Rec]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    contents <- T.readFile "./dat.txf" 
    let seps = splitOn "^\n" contents
    let recs = fmap (splitOn "\n") seps
    -- print $ fmap (\[x, y, z] -> Rec x y z) recs
    let tada = fmap (\[x, y, z] -> Rec x y z) recs
    mapM_ print tada

main
```

Produces:

```
Rec "Good" "id123" ""
Rec "Bad" "id456" ""
Rec "Middle" "id789" ""
```

The `\anonymous` function can take a `\[l,i,s,t]`.

Comment: Just to be clear as to why your functions didnt work:
the first one (that you now corrected) just failed the pattern matching: `[a,b,c]` is a list with three elements, which is different from a 3-tuple `(a,b,c)` .
the second one failed because `Rec` is a data constructor, but acts just like a function. In fact if you type `:t Rec` in your GHCi you will find something like `Rec :: Text -> Text -> Text -> Rec`, so you cannot pass it a tuple, which is exactly what the error says. You can fix this by 'uncurrying' it with `uncurry3`

Comment: Thanks.  How would you apply the uncurry3 fix?  Is that replace `print $ fmap (\x -> Rec (f x)) recs
                            where f [a,b,c] = (a,b,c)  ` with `print $ fmap (\x -> Rec $ uncurry3 x) recs`?

Comment: other way round, look at the type signature of uncurry: `(\x -> uncurry3 Rec x)`

Comment: I'm seeing `:t uncurry3` `uncurry3 :: forall a b c d. (a -> b -> c -> d) -> (a, b, c) -> d` and `print $ fmap (\x -> uncurry3 Rec x) recs` yielding `Couldn't match type ‘[Text]’ with ‘(Text, Text, Text)’
      Expected type: [(Text, Text, Text)]
        Actual type: [[Text]]`

Comment: Yeah you need to apply `f` in order to get a tuple from the list. Edited the comment now

Comment: Doesn't let me edit but should be `(\x -> uncurry3 Rec (f x))`