# Why is this lambda function a parse error with pattern matching and cons operator?

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am trying to parse a record from a lists of lists (continuing from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643003/from-a-list-of-lists-to-a-list-of-data-records)).

Here's my record

```
data Record = Record Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text deriving (Show, Generic)
```

This syntax works:

```
parseRecords :: [[Text]] -> [Record]
parseRecords = map (\[f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,_] -> Record f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9)
```

This syntax checks, but has me fixed at 10 parameters.  I would rather be able to have more than that and ignore the ones greater by pattern matching them into a [_] list I will not pass along.  I tried the following:

```
parseRecords = map (\f1:f2:f3:f4:f5:f6:f7:f8:f9:[_] -> Record f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9)
```

This, however, fails with:

```
Parse error (line 27, column 24): parse error on input ‘:’
```

I could have sworn I saw this kind of pattern matching used in lambdas before.  What am I missing that my colon operators are a parse error?  It is hard to interrogate what's going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: You need an extra pair of parentheses around the pattern: `(\(f1:f2:f3:f4:f5:f6:f7:f8:f9:[_]) -> Record f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9)`

Comment: The `[_]` is also wrong, you want just `_`. `[_]` is a pattern matching a list with exactly one element in it.

Comment: Are you sure you want a custom data type with 9 fields, all of the same type? This is going to get very cumbersome very quickly (it's pretty painful just seeing the brief code in your question). I don't know the use case, but I would strongly advise, at the very least, using record syntax if each piece of data has some simple characterisation.

Comment: @RobinZigmond no.  My next step is to change this and use smart constructors, but need to crawl before I can run. Couldn't do much at all before I could pattern match and have it compile.

Comment: I appreciate the help everybody, but it really isn't easy to learn this stuff.  Answers are often varying degrees of venomous RTFM and "closed-duplicate."  I've read the books, but need practice, and asking for help on the internet takes some thick skin.  As you can see, the compiler wasn't super helpful here, but I appreciate you all helped me find the error.  It saved me maybe half a day of not understanding the bug and not having much to go on.

Comment: Also, even with @duplode spelling it out for me, my initial error reading that was `parseRecords = map ((\f1:f2:.. ) ->`   rather than `parseRecords = map (\(f1:f2:.. ) -> ` Note to be careful on what is being `\lamba`'d for anyone else reading this in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like you need parentheses around patterns in function bindings,

```
f (x:xs) = ...
```

you need parentheses around patterns in lambdas:

```
parseRecords = map (\ (f1:f2:f3:f4:f5:f6:f7:f8:f9:_) -> Record f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9)
                      -------pattern----------------
                   ------------------lambda function--------------------------------------
```

Sometimes parentheses can be omitted, but not always. The list patterns are:

```
[]           matches     []
(x:xs)       matches     [x, ...]      so that   (x:xs)   == [x]   ++ xs
(x:y:xs)     matches     [x, y, ...]   so that   (x:y:xs) == [x]   ++ (y:xs)
                                                          == [x,y] ++ xs
..... and so on ......
```

This is because `:` associates to the right, so `(x:y:xs)` is actually `(x:(y:xs))`.

Lastly, `_` is a wildcard. It is like a variable pattern like `x` or `y` or `xs`, but without a name. Each `_` is different from another, as if it was named with a unique, though missing, name.